# Azure cannot create SendGrid account, validation failed

Tags: azure, sendgrid

Tried to create a *free* Sendgrid account in Azure portal, but get the error code and error message:

```
ResourcePurchaseValidationFailed
User failed validation to purchase resources.
```

The subscription is "Visual Studio Premium with MSDN"

Anybody an idea how to solve this?

Comment: I have same issue but with other subscription.

Answer (score 0):

I tried this on three different accounts and all failed. When I came back 2 hours later, I was able to provision it.

It is unclear if one truly has to wait for at least 30 minutes, but it seems like a try again after 1 hour to 24 hours later seems to do the trick.